# Phantomjs equivalent of browser's "Save Page As... Webpage, complete"

Tags: webkit, phantomjs, casperjs

For my application I need to programmatically save a copy of a webpage HTML along with the images and resources needed to render it. Browsers have this functionality in their `Save page as...` `Webpage, complete` options.

It is of course easy to save the rendered HTML of a page using phantomjs or casperjs. However, I have not seen any examples of combining this with downloading the associated images, and doing the needed DOM changes to use the downloaded images.

Given that this functionality exists in webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari) I'm surprised it isn't in phantomjs -- or perhaps I just haven't found it!

Comment: No, PhantomJS doesn't provide this functionality. You would have to script it, but it will probably get very long considering proper handling of things like background images and web fonts.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Cool, that's what I was afraid of. It's a shame that this functionality is in Webkit but not exposed via Phantomjs or casperjs.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively the PhantomJS, you can use the CasperJS to achieve the required result. CasperJS is a framework based on the PhantomJS, however, with a variety of modules and classes that support and complement the PhantomJS.

An example of a script that you can use is:

```
casper.test.begin('test script', 0, function(test) {
    casper.start(url);

    casper.then(function myFunction(){
        //...
    });

    casper.run(function () {
        //...
        test.done();
    });
});
```

With this script, within a "step", you can perform your downloads, be it a single image of a document, the page, a print or whatever.
Take a study on the **download** methods, **getPageContent** and **capture** / **captureSelector** in [this link](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html).

I hope these pointers can help you to go further!

Comment: CasperJS doesn't really help in doing this. It has an integrated resource management, but you would still have to download those resources.

Comment: @Diego Yes, I know about Casperjs (it's mentioned in my question).

Comment: I think you'd better better detail what you want to accomplish! From what you wrote, I understand you want to save the contents of a complete web page. CasperJS do it!